# HTML5 widget seekTo not working

Tags: html, soundcloud

I'm having trouble getting the seekTo method to work with the HTML5 widget API. Basing this on the [API docs](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget) and [examples](http://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/html5-widget-api).

I'm able to play my player with:

```
widget.play();
```

But:

```
widget.seekTo(10000);
```

Doesn't seem to do anything. I thought maybe I needed to `seekTo`, then `play`. But that didn't work either. Does anyone have a working example of `seekTo` in action that they could share?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately its not Asynchronous, you have to first see when the player is ready. After its ready, you have to play the sound. After you play the sound, you seek to it.

```
var soundcloud=SC.Widget('soundcloudPlayer');

soundcloud.bind (SC.Widget.Events.READY,function(){
soundcloud.play();
}); 

soundcloud.bind (SC.Widget.Events.PLAY,function(){
soundcloud.seekTo(845700);
});
```